# How to extract and display data from an API?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to download and display the API data from a website. Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
      function loadJSON(file, callback) {

      var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
      xobj.open('GET', file, true);
      xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
              callback(xobj.responseText);
            }
      };
      xobj.send(null);
   }
      var outerSpace;
      loadJSON("http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json", gotData);

      function gotData(data) {
          outerSpace = data;
      }

      if (outerSpace) {
        console.log(outerSpace.people.name);
      }
```

This is the full API ( not much ).

```
    {
"number": 3,
"message": "success",
"people": [
{
"name": "Peggy Whitson",
"craft": "ISS"
},
{
"name": "Fyodor Yurchikhin",
"craft": "ISS"
},
{
"name": "Jack Fischer",
"craft": "ISS"
}
]
}
```

Shouldn't console.log output "Peggy Whitson"? I get no error messages but the console receives no messages. If anyone could help me find a fix I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: first, remove the if statement so you can see if you got an 404 or 500 error from the server:

[if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
              callback(xobj.responseText);
            }]

Comment: Also `people` is an array, so you cannot call `people.name` directly. Use `outerSpace.people[0].name` to get the first name.

Comment: @Abiezer no error message.

Comment: @Racil Hilan still didn't log anything.

Comment: I said **also** because this is not the main issue. If it was the main issue, I would've posted it as an answer instead of a comment. But once you fix the main issue, you will have an error on this line and need to fix it.

Comment: @RacilHilan What's the main issue then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the other answers are well and good, I just wanted to point out where I think the misunderstanding lies:

```
  // Here you create the callback.
  // It will run later when the ajax-call completes.
  function gotData(data) {
    outerSpace = data;
  }

  // This however runs immediately and only once.
  // outerSpace will *always* be undefined at this point 
  // Because gotData has not yet completed. 
  // (The whole thing about ajax-calls are that they complete *later*.)
  if (outerSpace) {
    console.log(outerSpace.people.name);
  }
```

You treat `if` as if it could mean `when` (sadly there is no such thing) All you have is your callback, so you have to put your logic there:.

```
  function gotData(data) {
    outerSpace = data;
    if (outerSpace) {
      console.log(outerSpace.people.name);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues.  Your function gotData is loading your data as a string so you need to parse that string into JSON:

```
function gotData(data) {
    outerSpace = JSON.parse(data);
}
```

Second, people is an array, so if you only want to grab one of the names you need to specify the index of that object.

```
if (outerSpace) {
    console.log(outerSpace.people[0].name);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting no error message but still no console message. Here's my code:      https://codepad.co/snippet/5WJlz3Lh

Comment: You can add logging earlier in your code.  For example, I might add `console.log(data)` in your gotData function while testing to see that you are retrieving the data properly.